# Detectar cuando se abre y se cierra una aplicación en Android

Tags: android-studio

Necesito saber cuando se abre y cuando se cierra una aplicación de terceros en Android, para así desencadenar tareas en mi aplicación.

Llevo todo el día intentándolo con BroadcastReceiver, pero creo que no es la solución y estoy completamente perdido.

Cabe destacar que necesito que independientemente de que mi aplicación se esté ejecutando o no, necesito obtener esa información. Por ejemplo, que si se abre Facebook, mi aplicación pueda detectarlo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a que realices el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente revisa [ask]. Podrías anexar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: con cerrar te refieres a ponerla en 2do plano o de matarla?

Comment: Para las nuevas versiones de android esta capado el poder ver las apps que se inician y mucha más información a menos que el dispositivo este rooteado

Answer (score 1):

Para saber cuando la aplicación entra a segundo plano o a primer plano, usa el ciclo de vida de la activity:

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Más acerca de esto [The Acitivity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java)

Comment: **Esto es incorrecto ya que no aplica para una aplicación de terceros**, solo sobre la misma aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, parece ser que no había explicado bien lo que necesitaba. He editado la pregunta para que se entienda mejor, un saludo.