# Detectar si otra aplicación se abre en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio

Buen día, si me podrían ayudar por favor. Sucede que quiero detectar en mi aplicación de Android Studio, al minimizarlo o cerrarlo, cuando abra otra aplicación, por ejemplo WhatsApp o Google, mi aplicación lo detecte. El servicio en segundo plano, ya lo tengo, sin embargo mi función para saber cuando se abre otra aplicación solo detecta el mío y del sistema operativo del celular, pero cuando abro otra app, sigue saliendo del sistema. Sé que hay otra pregunta igual [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240944/detectar-cuando-se-abre-y-se-cierra-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android), pero no hay alguna respuesta de lo dicho.

Código del Service

```
    public class AlwaysService extends Service {

    public boolean threadIsTerminate = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        threadIsTerminate = true;
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (threadIsTerminate) {
                runForever();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        final String id_channel = "Foreground Service ID";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id_channel, id_channel,
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
                getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
                Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, id_channel)
                        .setContentTitle("Service Enabled").
                        setContentText("Service is running").
                        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                startForeground(1001, notification.build());
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        threadIsTerminate = false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void runForever() {
        String nameApp = isAppRunning(this);
        Log.e("TAG", nameApp);
    }
    public static String isAppRunning(final Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        return runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    }

}
```

Mensaje en el Logcat:

> *2022-08-05 10:32:00.362 20677-20716/multiverse.crud_sqlite E/TAG: multiverse.crud_sqlite*
> *2022-08-05 10:32:02.372 20677-20716/multiverse.crud_sqlite E/TAG: multiverse.crud_sqlite*
> *2022-08-05 10:32:04.384 20677-20716/multiverse.crud_sqlite E/TAG: com.miui.home*
> *2022-08-05 10:32:06.396 20677-20716/multiverse.crud_sqlite E/TAG: com.miui.home*
> *2022-08-05 10:32:08.399 20677-20716/multiverse.crud_sqlite E/TAG: com.miui.home*

Cuando abro otras aplicaciones sigue saliendo el "com.miui.home", si falta información me comentan por favor.

MainActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlwaysService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(intent);
        }
```